# Expected value of a fair coin toss

Tags: probability, expectation

Richard has 16 fair coins numbered 1 to 16 on one side and the other side is marked with 0. Richard tosses these 16 coins.

Let $X$ be the sum of the numbers on the coins.

What is the expected value of X?

It would make sense that it would be sum from 1 to 16 divided by 2, but I don't really understand why is that true formally.

Answer (score 4):

By linearity of expectation, it is the sum of the expectation for each coin.  Let's take a look at coin $i$ which has $i$ on one side and zero on the other.  The expectation of this coin is $i/2$.  Therefore, your intuition is correct, you simply sum from 1 to 16 and divide by two (which is the same as summing half of each summand)

Answer (score 0):

The coins are independent, then you sum the individual expectations
$$\frac12+\frac22+\frac32+\cdots\frac{16}2.$$

Comment: The fact that the coins are independent plays no part in this. Linearity of expectation is also valid by dependence.